# Existence of a path consisting of only essential/inessential vertices

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

When learning definition of essential and inessential vertices, out of curiosity, I am looking for a graph which contains a path that only consists of essential/inessential vertices.

A vertex is essential iff removing this vertex will not change the size of any maximum matching. A vertex is inessential iff the opposite happens.

So far I only find one example which meets my condition:

1. A cycle has only essential or inessential vertices so I will put "cycle" into my list.

Meanwhile, I would like to know if there is a graph which will never contain such a path that ONLY consists of essential/inessential vertices. For example, for a complete bipartite graph $K_(m, n)$ where $m < n$, such a path never exists.

Could you anyone interested in this question provide some examples? If you could tell me some graphs which contain or will never contain a path that consist of only essential/inessential paths, that will be great. 
Also, beside cycle, I would like to see some planar graphs which can meet my requirement.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please define what "essential" and "inessential" means in this context?

Comment: Yup. Being an essential vertex means that the removal of that vertex will not affect the size of any maximum matching in that graph. Being an inessential vertex means the opposite.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ to contain those definitions. Readers should no have to look in the comments to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry for not providing the definitions. I edited the question and hopefully it seems more clear to you.